# MySQL Disable Foreign Key Checks: What happens to "On Delete"?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Example, given following **airports** table:

```
id
name
country_id (foreign key, ON DELETE will set it to null)
```

Then:

1. Turn foreign key checks off
2. Drop the countries table

Will all airports have the country_id set to null or not (because foreign key checks are turned off)?

Edit: I have tried it and country_id was not set to null. My question is basically whether the `ON DELETE` is at all regarded in case of turned off foreign key checks.

Comment: So.. I just tried this out, it took exactly 32 second to create 2 tables, add 1 record to each, disable fk checks, drop a table. The point is not in 32 seconds, it could have been 5 minutes - the point is - how come you didn't try it before asking?

Comment: I had tried it but I was not sure if it was a matter of wrong setup or anything. So I figured I'd ask how it is in general.

Answer (score 2):

When you disable foreign key checks, you have the opportunity to put your database into an inconsistent state.

That is, you can force values in foreign key columns to referencing values (or even a whole table in your case) that are gone.

It's up to you to avoid doing that.

On a similar note, did you know that an electrician can electrocute themselves if they touch a live wire with a metal tool? They try not to do that.

Comment: Thank you Bill. I was using this for the rollback of migrations and for that case it was a useful state.